# Add a .xlsx extension to a variable in Python

Tags: python

I have some Python code that pulls data from a pdf file and converts it into excel. It then grabs specific data from that excel file and saves it to a new excel file. I want to name the final excel file something unique each time and thought datetime.now().isoformat() would be a good solution. So I save datetime.now().isoformat() as a string and then want to add the .xlsx extension to that string for a unique name. But I can't seem to figure out how to append .xlsx to the variable.

```
from spire.pdf.common import \*
from spire.pdf import \*
import os
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from datetime import datetime
import xlsxwriter

current_dateTime = datetime.now().isoformat()
**#This is where I create the variable with the .xlsx extension**
dt = str(current_dateTime) + ".xlsx"

pdf = PdfDocument()
pdf.LoadFromFile("c:/Documents/Projects/file.pdf")

pdf.SaveToFile("excel/template.xlsx", FileFormat.XLSX)
pdf.Close()

folder = 'excel'
**#This is where I try to create the output file with the .xlsx extension**
output_file = dt

output_wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
output_sheet = output_wb.active
output_sheet.title = 'Bearskin'

cells = \['BQ34', 'G13', 'J22'\]

for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    if filename.endswith('.xlsx'):
    file = os.path.join(folder, filename)
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
    values = \[workbook.active\[cell\].value for cell in cells\]
output_sheet.append(values)

output_sheet.insert_rows(1)

output_sheet\['A1'\]= "Section"
output_sheet\['B1'\]= "Operation"
output_sheet\['C1'\]= "Depth"
output_sheet\['D1'\]= "Duration"
output_sheet\['E1'\]= "Cumulative Hours"
output_sheet\['F1'\]= "Cumulative Days"

output_wb.save(output_file)
```

Comment: You are saving the output files to your current directory, not to the 'excel' folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can concat string in multiple ways, one of is: `output_file = str(dt) + ".xlsx"`.

For more advanced usage, you can use the built-in `format` and `%` functions which work like the C `printf` function.

Example:

```py
output_file = "{}.xlsx".format(dt))
```

EDIT:

You receive an `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` because your file name contains invalid characters (from the file system point of view). Unless you absolutely want to stick with the ISO time format, you can also use the `strftime` function to change the resulting time string representation.

```py
dt = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S.%s")
output_file = "{}.xlsx".format(dt))
```

This will result in a file name of the form: `20240404T102547.1712219147.xlsx`

Comment: I tried output_file = "{}.xlsx".format(dt) and I received this error: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '2024-03-29T04:57:43.441168.xlsx'

Comment: output_file = str(dt) + ".xlsx" returns the same error message.

Comment: when I change dt = str(current_dateTime) + ".xlsx" to dt = "this" it works. So the problem must be pulling in datetime.now().isoformat() . I guess I need to figure out another way to create a unique file name at run time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was pulling in the datetime and trying to use it as the variable for dt. When I create a random string with:

```
(''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=12)))
```

it works. So for anyone trying to do this, create a random string instead of trying to use datetime for the variable.

Comment: Using datetime isn't the problem... It's the format you chose. Files just cannot have colons in the name on windows

Comment: You are correct. This also worked: dt = now.strftime("%Y%m%d_%S") because it saved only numbers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a unique filename, you can also try the unix time.

```
from datetime import datetime

outputfile = "{}.xlsx".format(str(datetime.utcnow().timestamp()).replace('.', ''))
```